# Group_concat with columns of a particular type in the first

Tags: mysql, sql

My tables are:

```
Parent_Child (Parent_SSN, Child_SSN)
Person (SSN, Name, age, sex)
School (Child_SSN, School_Name)
```

I want to select the parents(female,male) who have atleast one of their children in a particular school `'X'`.I have a working query and my mysql query is:

```
select group_concat(p.name) from person p,parentchild pc,school s 
where s.schoolname='X' and s.childssn=pc.childssn and p.ssn=pc.parentssn 
group by pc.childssn
```

This displays the result as `parent(male,female)` but I want the result in `(female,male) form` and if I group it by parent.sex it displays results in individual rows and not in a single row.I am out of ideas.

Sample desired output:

```
name

Angela,Jim
```

Output of my above existing query:

```
name

Jim,Angela
```

Comment: Could you show the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76ba4/15) for  you.

```
SELECT DISTINCT group_concat(p.name ORDER BY p.sex Asc) 
FROM Person p JOIN Parent_Child pc ON p.ssn=pc.Parent_SSN 
          JOIN School s  ON s.Child_SSN = pc.Child_SSN
WHERE s.School_Name='X' 
GROUP By pc.Child_SSN;
```

Comment: It's awesome thank you very much.Your logic is way better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, might possible using sort

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( p.name ORDER BY p.name DESC ) from person p,parentchild pc,school s 
where s.schoolname='X' and s.childssn=pc.childssn and p.ssn=pc.parentssn 
group by pc.childssn
```

Comment: Doesn't work and also I want a query which is not data dependent I want a general query which puts the parent with type female in the first and type male in the second.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ORDER BY inside the GROUP_CONCAT function in this way :

Try this

```
SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT p.name ORDER BY p.name Asc) 
FROM person p JOIN parentchild pc ON p.ssn=pc.parentssn 
              JOIN school s  ON s.childssn = pc.childssn
WHERE s.schoolname='X' 
GROUP By pc.childssn
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function%5Fgroup-concat

Comment: The sorting works only for result set with one value and fails for result set with more than one value.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow managed to get the results using join here is my working query.

```
select * from (select distinct p.name from person p,parentchild pc,school s where s.schoolname='X' and s.childssn=pc.childssn and p.ssn=pc.parentssn and p.sex='F')q1 join (select distinct p.name from person p,parentchild pc,school s where s.schoolname='X' and s.childssn=pc.childssn and p.ssn=pc.parentssn and p.sex='M')q
```

I want to still know whether it is possible to sort items by a particular condition in group_concat result set which will affect it's postion in the group_concat result set.

Comment: When I try this query id doesn't match what you said was your desired output.

Comment: It works for me.I have just joined the female parent with male parent.